# Error: Na/NaN argument when plotting graphs

Tags: r

This seems to come up, sometimes, when I try to plot graphs.

```
Error in (Midpoint.NO.TEL1.1[k, 2] - 250):(Midpoint.NO.TEL1.1[k, 2] +  : NA/NaN argument
```

How is it possible that, sometimes, the programme is able to plot graphs using this exact same code and sometimes not? How can I solve this?

```
attach(ChromoSizes)
NO.TEL1.X1<-c(1:ChrSizes[1])
NO.TEL1.Y1<-rep(0,ChrSizes[1])
attach(FullMap.TEL1)
results <- matrix(0, nrow=1182, ncol=501)
 for (k in 1:1182) {
results[k,1:501] <- NO.TEL1.Y1[(Midpoint.NO.TEL1.1[k,2]-250) : (Midpoint.NO.TEL1.1[k,2]+250)]
 }
 pileup <- colMeans(results)
plot(pileup, type = "l",col="dark blue",lwd=2,xlab ="Distance relative to DSB (bp)",ylab = "Nucleosome Occupacy")
```

Comment: Could you let us know where ChromoSizes comes from? I cannot reproduce your error at the moment.

Comment: ChromoSizes is a table where I took the ChrSize [1] data.

Comment: can you share this data? possibly using dput(ChromoSizes)

Comment: Hey! Solved the problem already. Seems I downloaded the data (FullMap.Tel1) in two different formats and that's the error. I kept using both without realising it. Thanks though!

Comment: no worries. In general it's not good practice to use attach, because of the reasons you have experienced. Better to use df$variable to identify what you want to use.